# Undesirable scrollbar when sliding mobile menu is displayed

Tags: css, scrollbar

When viewport width goes below 1068px, [my page](http://goo.gl/M783K1) (login = "mmt" | pass = "mmt_nv2014") hides top menu and enables a mobile menu triggred by hamburger icon top left.

When mobile menu appears the whole page goes right to make room for it. Problem: this creates an horizontal scrollbar. Question: is there a way to avoid this scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following CSS to fix this

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This hides the content to the right of your screen. Please see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp for the complete explanation, but it does what you want to do.